# Chart.js - overlapping percentages are sitting in the middle of pie/doughnut graphs and not sure where its coming from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

[Rendered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbkgw.png)

Everything is working fine and looks good. Only issue is the percentages are showing right in the middle overlapping in the same place whether it being a pie or doughnut chart.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Doughnut, Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js';


// Register the necessary Chart.js components
ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

const MonthlyTargetCharts = () => {
    const [consignmentData, setConsignmentData] = useState(null);
    const [nonConsignmentData, setNonConsignmentData] = useState(null);

    // Helper function to calculate the percentage
    const calculatePercentage = (value) => (value ? parseFloat(value).toFixed(2) : "0");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_MONTHLY_TARGET_PRIMARY);
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                const jsonData = await response.json();
                if (jsonData.data && jsonData.data.length > 0) {
                    const data = jsonData.data[0];
                    setConsignmentData({
                        labels: ['Percentage of Consignment', 'Remaining to 100%'],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [parseFloat(data["percentage of consignment"]), 100 - parseFloat(data["percentage of consignment"])],
                            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)', 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6)'],

                        }],
                    });
                    setNonConsignmentData({
                        labels: ['Percentage of Non-Consignment', 'Remaining to 100%'],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [parseFloat(data["percentage of non consignment"]), 100 - parseFloat(data["percentage of non consignment"])],
                            backgroundColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)', 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6)'],
                        }],
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error('No data returned');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Fetch failed:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);



    return (
        <>
            <h2 className='sales-targets-title' style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}>Sales Targets</h2>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
                {consignmentData && (
                    <div className="chart-container consignment">
                        <h2>Consignment Target</h2>
                        <Doughnut data={consignmentData} key="consignmentChart" />
                        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            <h3>{calculatePercentage(consignmentData.datasets[0].data[0])}% Completed</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                {nonConsignmentData && (
                    <div className="chart-container non-consignment">
                        <h2>Non-Consignment Target</h2>
                        <Doughnut data={nonConsignmentData} key="nonConsignmentChart" />
                        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            <h3>{calculatePercentage(nonConsignmentData.datasets[0].data[0])}% Completed</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

I have tried uninstalling chart.js and reinstalling and that didn't work. I am on Chart.js 4.4.1. I tried disabling the tooltip but that didn't change anything. the value remain there. They are the correct percentages overlapping there but I want to remove them completely.

Comment: There is normally no text in the center of a chart.js doughnut, see this [codesandbox preview](https://lsfcvw-5173.csb.app/) ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/quirky-fog-lsfcvw)) (the styling of your css classes are missing, but that's unlikely to create those text items). You must be using datalabels or something else that's not in the code you posted.

Comment: You should try to make your code, or a part of your code that presents this error, available live online, on a dev server or as a codesandbox or a stackblitz.